# eclipse perspective messed up, reset not helping

Tags: eclipse

I somehow messed up my perspective then I clicked reset perspective. This gives me back the package manager on the left. problems/javadoc/declarations on the bottom. Task list and outline as 2 separate windows on the right and a big empty space in the middle where the code is supposed to be. When I open up some code it ends up  in the bottom window and there's that big hole where the code window used to go. I can drag and drop the code into that empty space, but when I try to drag the code window bigger to fill up the entire space it won't let me past a certain point. I'm left with a gap above the coding window that's bothering me. It seems Eclipse is leaving that space for me to drag other perspectives into, however dragging more perspectives into that empty space doesn't make it go away, it's still the same size. How do I get rid of this space?

Comment: By your writing I can say that your understanding on eclipse perspective is wrong.  Post the screen shot and explain. If not able to attached screenshot share it on imgur.com. Also do format your post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close eclipse if it's open
2. Navigate to your workspace folder
3. Further navigate down into `.metadata` then `.plugins` (These are hidden files, use terminal or look up how to show hidden files in your OS)
4. Delete the `org.eclipse.e4.workbench` folder
   [image: org.eclipse.e4.workbench selected in OSX Finder]
5. Restart Eclipse
6. If it still doesn't look right click `Window > New Window`
7. If it still isn't fixed please let me know in the comments (it might be time to reinstall Eclipse)